# Really huge dictionary

Tags: java, data-structures

What's the best way to store a really large dictionary in Java and use it the best way during runtime? I would like to implement a complete dictionary and synonyms kind of  module.

**Update:**
Suggest any common design pattern which can be used for this requirement

Comment: How do you define "huge" and "large"?

Comment: Agreed -- database.  Note that, if it's worthwhile, you can cache recently-referenced DB entries, to speed up subsequent searches.

Comment: "*a complete dictionary and synonyms*" if it is only one language, that won't be very large...

Comment: for now it is one language, it will grow to multiple languages.

Comment: Storing 1,000,000 entries in a HashMap consisting of just a filename string and a reference to an 80-byte object would use roughly around 100~200 MB of memory. Which is not much considering today's RAM sizes, even if it required 10 times as much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a database for this kind of stuff. It's meant for that. If you don't want to have a central DB server, then just use one of the embeddable databases. At least you'll follow a standard pattern and still get the benefits of being able to work local.

http://db.apache.org/derby/

http://hsqldb.org/

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 5):

One of the simpliest and fastest (to code with) db is [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It should be good enough for your needs. I have successfully used sqlite to store several gigabytes of data without any problems.